# Can't set the locale (man-db.cron)

Tags: linux, centos, locale

Everyday I am receiving an email with the following content:

```
/etc/cron.daily/man-db.cron:
mandb: can't set the locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct
```

When I check the results of of `/etc/locale.conf`, I see the result is set to

```
LANG=en_EN.UTF-8
```

When I run the command `locale` I see the following output:

```
-sh-4.2$ locale
LANG=nl_NL.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Now I see that the `LC_ALL` is not set but when I set it using the following command:

```
-sh-4.2$ export LC_ALL=nl_NL.UTF-8
```

and then run the command locale again

```
LC_ALL=nl_NL.UTF-8
```

you will see that it is set but somehow when I go out of SSH and check sometime later, I will see again that it is not set and I keep receiving the email.

My question is, how can I solve the locale issue so I don't keep receiving the emails from `man-db.cron`.

I am using CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core).

Answer (score 1):

In CentOS 7 you can use `localectl status` command to view the settings of your locale. If it is not set than use :-

```
# List locales
localectl list-locales | grep en_EN

# set your locale
localectl set-locale LANG=en_EN.UTF-8

# also, set your local key map 
localectl set-keymap us
localectl set-x11-keymap us
```

Check your status again :- `localectl status`

Answer (score 1):

I solved this on a Raspberry Pi 4 running Arch Linux by uncommenting `en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8` in `/etc/locale.gen` and creating the files for that [locale](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Locale):

```
sudoedit /etc/locale.gen
sudo locale-gen
```

After that, `man` stops issuing this warning:

> can't set the locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct